# my program isnt writing to process memory. how do i debug this? im new to wpm and rpm

Tags: c++

`

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <Tlhelp32.h>


HANDLE hProc = NULL;
DWORD pID;

bool attachProc(char* procName)
{
    PROCESSENTRY32 procEntry32;
    procEntry32.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    auto hProcSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS, 0);

    if(hProcSnap == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        std::cout << "FAILED to take snapshot of processes\n";
        return false;
    }

    while(Process32Next(hProcSnap, &procEntry32))
    {
        std::cout << procEntry32.szExeFile << std::endl;
        if (procEntry32.th32ProcessID != 996)
        {

            if (!strcmp(procName, procEntry32.szExeFile))
        {
            std::cout << "found process " << procEntry32.szExeFile << " with process id " << procEntry32.th32ProcessID << std::endl;
            hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,FALSE,procEntry32.th32ProcessID);
            pID = procEntry32.th32ProcessID;

            if (hProc == NULL)
            {
                std::cout << "failed getting handle to process" << std::endl;
            }

            CloseHandle(hProcSnap);
            return true;
        }

        }
    }

    std::cout << "couldnt find " << procName << "in the process snapshot" << std::endl;
    CloseHandle(hProcSnap);
    return false;
}

template <class dataType>
void wpm(dataType valToWrite, DWORD adressToWrite)
{
    WriteProcessMemory(hProc, (PVOID)adressToWrite, &valToWrite, sizeof(dataType), 0);
}

template <class dataType>
dataType rpm(DWORD adressToRead)
{
    dataType rpmBuffer;
    ReadProcessMemory(hProc, (PVOID)adressToRead, &rpmBuffer, sizeof(dataType), 0);
    return rpmBuffer;
}

int main()
{
    DWORD memoryAdress = 0x288469A7A28;
    int value = 1

    attachProc((char*)"dummy.exe");
    while (true)
    {
        wpm<int>(value, memoryAdress);
    }

}
```

`

i think there is a problem in getting the handle but i dont know where or how do i debug this.
is there any different way on how to get a handle? bestsides FindWindow() because this doesnt work either

i was trying to write process memory but id didnt work for some reason the adress should be good i tested it in cheat engine multiple times

Comment: Are you certain that the process ID is 996 ?  The ProcessID is unique for each instance of a process and will definitely change every time you restart the application.  Just filtering on the process exe name should be enough.  And where did you get that address???  Are you 100% certain it is ALWAYS a valid address in the address space of the target process?

Comment: thank you for responding! i know the pid changes every time but the dummy.exe is split into two processes for some reason and only one of them is the correct one, where im able to edit the values

Comment: Have you tried reading back the memory using rpm()?  Read before writing, to make sure you read something other than 1, then write, then read again to check if it has changed.   Just to be sure.

Comment: nope nothing it returns a 0 it should return a different value that is nowhere close to 0
also the datatypes are correct too

Comment: Your program does not check (and it should) if the calls to ReadProcessMemory() and WriteProcessMemory() are successful.  The error could be coming from there.

Comment: how do i check if the calls to either of the functions are successful? does it return an error? or bool?

Comment: The documentation is online, google is your friend, at least when finding documentation is concerned.. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/memoryapi/nf-memoryapi-writeprocessmemory